# Глюк с полем input text на мобильной версии сайта в Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, css3, html5, yii2, bootstrap

Имеется поле input с типом text. При его первом посещении со смартфона (чистые куки и кэш) невозможно вбить в это поле текст. При клике на поле клавиатура выезжает, но при печати текст не появляется.
Если сделать refresh, проблема исчезает. И это только в в Google Chrome.

Сайт написан на yii2, bootstrap, но файл со стилями подключал свой.
При полном выключении стилей косяк не пропадает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

Код:

```
<body class="waitMe_body">
    <?php $this->beginBody(); ?>
    <div class="upWrapper">
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <section>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="upperSection">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <h1 class="uph1">Тут заголовок</h1>
                                <p class="upText">Тут какой-то текст</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <form action="тут ссылка"?>" method="get">
                                    <input type="text" maxlength="17" placeholder="Enter your VIN" name="vin" required autocomplete="off" style="">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Run Report" class="btn btn-danger">
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
```

Вот весь CSS код на это поле(из разных файлов):

```
*::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.upperSection form input[type="text"] {
    width: 100%;
}
.upperSection form input[type="text"] {
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
input, button, select, textarea {
    font-family: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
}
button, input, optgroup, select, textarea {
    color: inherit
    margin: 0;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: может из-за вот этого? `<form action="..."?>" method="get">`

Comment: Нет. Это я ссылки и тексты убрал, чтобы пост не загромождать.

Answer (score -1):

Проблема решилась сама собой. Это был глюк на Google Chrome браузере для мобильных устройств. После очередного обновления проблема исчезла.